# io.sentry.SentryClientFactory - Error creating valid DSN from: 'https://public:private@host:port/1'

Tags: java, sentry

I am new to Sentry followed [this](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration-via-properties-file)

[and this](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/usage/)

and followed the same steps and the code I have an sbt project in which I created `sentry.properties` file its contents are

```
dsn=https://public:private@host:port/1
```

and placed it under `src/main/resources` when the code runs (the same code given the link above ) following exception is thrown'

```
18:19:26.745 [run-main-1] DEBUG io.sentry.config.Lookup - Found dsn=https://public:private@host:port/1 in sentry.properties.
18:19:26.754 [run-main-1] ERROR io.sentry.SentryClientFactory - Error creating valid DSN from: 'https://public:private@host:port/1'.
io.sentry.dsn.InvalidDsnException: Invalid DSN, the following properties aren't set '[host, public key]'
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.validate(Dsn.java:209) ~[sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.<init>(Dsn.java:66) ~[sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.<init>(Dsn.java:41) ~[sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.SentryClientFactory.resolveDsn(SentryClientFactory.java:73) [sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.SentryClientFactory.sentryClient(SentryClientFactory.java:42) [sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:81) [sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:44) [sentry-1.7.16.jar:na]
    at sentry.SentryDemo$.main(SentryDemo.scala:16) [classes/:na]
    at sentry.SentryDemo.main(SentryDemo.scala) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84) [logging-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248) [run-0.13.16.jar:0.13.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
[error] (run-main-1) io.sentry.dsn.InvalidDsnException: Invalid DSN, the following properties aren't set '[host, public key]'
io.sentry.dsn.InvalidDsnException: Invalid DSN, the following properties aren't set '[host, public key]'
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.validate(Dsn.java:209)
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.<init>(Dsn.java:66)
    at io.sentry.dsn.Dsn.<init>(Dsn.java:41)
    at io.sentry.SentryClientFactory.resolveDsn(SentryClientFactory.java:73)
    at io.sentry.SentryClientFactory.sentryClient(SentryClientFactory.java:42)
    at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:81)
    at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:44)
    at sentry.SentryDemo$.main(SentryDemo.scala:16)
    at sentry.SentryDemo.main(SentryDemo.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Is there anything I need to add in place of `dsn`in the properties file ? i am using sentry in my project which is not a web based project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DSN tells the Sentry SDK which instance of sentry to hit (for example `sentry.io`) and which project within Sentry the events belong to.

You need to get the DSN from Sentry and add to your project.
In Sentry, in the project settings page, you'll see: `Client keys (DSN)`:

[image: Sentry Client keys menu]

You'll then see the DSN like so:

[image: Example DSN]

Copy this (the button on the right), and paste on your `sentry.properties` replacing the placeholder: `https://public:private@host:port/1`